# Почему мой алгоритм медленный?

Tags: python

```
import math
def f(n):
  l = {}
  lst = [str(num) for num in range(1, n, 2) if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1))]
    for i in lst[::-1]:
      even = 0
      for j in i:
        if int(j) % 2 == 0:
          even += 1
        l[i] = even
    return int(max(l, key=l.get))
```

Этот код должен выводить простое число с наибольшим количество четных цифр, но я не укладываюсь в рамки 12000мс для 1000 <= n <= 5000000. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Зачем переводить числа в строку и потом опять переводить эту строку в число?

Comment: @Эникейщик Там числа в строку, а потом каждую цифру каждого бывшего числа в число.

Comment: @1woshibai Предлагаю как минимум не вычислять все простые числа в список, который потом переворачивать, чтобы начать проверять с большего. А вычислять простые числа в обратном порядке (от большего к меньшему) и сразу проверять (и никуда не складировать).

Comment: Цикл range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1) можно сократить вдвое, если делить только на нечетные:  range(3,int(math.sqrt(num))+1,2)

Comment: @GrAnd я использовал вашу подсказку, но время не улучшилось

Answer (score 0):

Если трошки подумать, а не сразу в лоб перебирать, то это число на первой же итерации находится.

Начинаем с конца и с числа, содержащего как можно больше четных цифр.

1. Кончаться должно на нечетное: [13579]
2. Начинаться с четного: [24]
3. В середине пока только четные: [02468] - 5 штук

Т.е первым шагом получаем проверку чисел от 4888889 до 2000001, где первая цифра - 2,4; последняя - любая нечетная; в центре 5 четных в любых комбинациях.

Если не найдется простого, следующим шагом проверяем такую комбинацию:

1. Кончаться должно на нечетное: [13579]
2. Начинаться с четного: [2468]
3. В середине пока только четные: [02468] - 4 штуки

Следующий шаг:

1. Кончаться должно на нечетное: [13579]
2. Начинаться с четного: [2468]
3. В середине пока только четные: [02468] - 3 штуки

Следующий шаг:

1. Кончаться должно на нечетное: [13579]
2. Начинаться с четного: [2468]
3. В середине пока только четные: [02468] - 2 штуки

Если не найдется, по второму кругу, добавляя одну нечетную в первые n-1 цифр.

Следующий шаг:

1. Кончаться должно на нечетное: [13579]
2. Начинаться с: [1-9]
3. В середине [0-9] - 5 штук
   п.п. 2 и 3 - из 6-ти чисел одно нечетное, остальные четные

и т.д.

Расписать код можно как угодно, нужно только перед проверкой чисел от 4888889 до 2000001 проверить границы диапазона. И вуаля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Начинаться с четного: [24]` С чего вдруг такое умозаключение? Если подать на вход, скажем, 1250, то правильный ответ - 1249. И он совсем не с 2 или с 4 начинается. А по вашему алгоритму куча каких-то лишних телодвижений, прежде чем он свалится на обычный перебор, который это число и обнаружит.

Comment: "число с наибольшим количество четных цифр для 1000 <= n <= 5000000" Логично, что число с наибольшим кол-вом четных цифр будет содержаться в диапазоне чисел с самым большим кол-вом цифр вообще. Это 7 цифр и диапазон 1000000 - 5000000, а из четных цифр, но само число иечетное - 2000001-4888889

Comment: Так это `n` подаётся на вход функции. И оно не равно 5000000 каждый раз, а лежит в указанном диапазоне.

Comment: Ну вот придумайте, как программно получить наибольшее нечетное число меньше заданного. Берем число. Если четное - отнимаем 1. Потом разбиваем на цифры и проверяем на четность. Если цифирь четная - минус 1. На каждом этапе проверяем или не выходит за пределы мин. границы диапазона. Аналогично получаем минимальноге число из максимального кол-ва цифр с макс. кол-вом четных цифр.

Comment: @GrAnd Да, я немного протупил, подумав, что найти нужно в диапазоне 1000-5000000. Но алгоритм по сути от этого не меняется. И да, проверять по ходу  на делимость на 3 и убрать 5 из нечетных в конце.